# Why is $ P(−y ≤ X ≤ y) = 2P(0 ≤ X ≤ y)$ and not just $P(0 ≤ X ≤ y)$ when the range of $y$ is $[0, ∞)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Given that $Y=|X|$ , the range of $y$ is $[0, ∞)$,

$P(Y ≤ y) = P(−y ≤ X ≤ y) = 2P(0 ≤ X ≤ y)$

My question is, why does $ P(−y ≤ X ≤ y)$ equal to  $2P(0 ≤ X ≤ y)$ and not just $P(0 ≤ X ≤ y)$ ?

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: You say $P(Y ≤ y) = P(−y ≤ X ≤ y)$.  What is the relationship between $X$ and $Y$? For example do you have $Y=|X|$?

Comment: Yes, that's what i have. sorry i should've mentioned that. Will edit it in

Comment: If $X$ is a continuous random variable, then $$P(-y\le X\le y)=P(-y\le X \le 0) + P(0\le X \le y).$$ If you have some more assumptions on $X$ (like that it is symmetric, e.g. normally distributed with mean $0$), you can say that $$P(-y\le X \le 0)=P(0\le X \le y).$$